# What specific design patterns should I implement for a web portal that allows customers to book multiple means(Flights,Car,Hotels) UML from a database

Tags: uml

I only have to draw up a UML class design for it.
The web portal should allow the user to pick from a hotel, or flight, or car rental or all 3 or 2 out of the 3. The user should be able to search through the products as a guest but will be redirected to register or login to purchase a product, Admins are allowed to remove or add products to the productdatabase. What I initially have is a general set up of the system however I need to implement design patterns. Now I already tried singleton but I see no reason for there to be only one instance in this portal.
[1st half of my UML class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VGBI.png)
[2nd half of my UML class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UswSu.png)

Comment: Your design is quite flawed (superfluous `id` attributes, etc.). It's also not readable as the associations appear criss-cross. Besides that the question is far too broad. You can not expect someone to come up with a design for your homework. If you have a specific question, try to boil it down.

Comment: If your professor urged you to use design patterns, look for what he used for teaching and re-use them. Else, there is no need to use any pattern for itself. A pattern is to be used where it fits. Not vice versa.